# Cannot use Breakpoint in PyCharm Professional 2018.1.3

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to use a breakpoint in PyCharm.

How can I run a breakpoint?

**I tried**

- CTRL + F8 doesn't do anything
- RUN --> Toggle Line Breakpoint is not available to choose

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879609/how-to-jump-between-breakpoint-in-jetbrains-pycharm-ide) can help you to resolve your problem.

Just put your breakpoints where you want an run with the debug mode

Comment: The problem is that I cannot put breakpoints whether normal or in debug mode.

Comment: To put breakpoints it's simple, just click at the right of your line number and a red circle will appear

Comment: I see. It worked now thank you. I clicked the whole time on the left side on the line number! :)